# How do you show a panel in VB dot net, if all the panels are created dynamically and sit in the exact same spot?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, panel

I am using Visual Studio 2022 and my language of choice is VB.  When the program starts it creates Multiple Panels that are located in the same position created from data from a database.

No matter what I do, I can not get any of the panels to show.  I can search for the panels and verify the panels exist, I can search the panels and verify that there are buttons in the panels.  However I can not get each individual panel to show.

I am going to list all the panels that are created in the order they are created and they are all in the exact same position and size.

1. panel2
2. pnlDeptItems01
3. pnlDeptItems11
4. pnlDeptItems22
5. pnlDeptItems23
6. pnlDeptItems24
7. pnlDeptItems25
8. pnlDeptItems26
9. pnlDeptItems27
10. pnlDeptItems28
11. pnlDeptItems29
12. pnlDeptItems32
13. pnlDeptItems54
14. pnlDeptItems82
15. pnlDeptItems83
16. pnlDeptItems84
17. pnlDeptItems85
18. pnlDeptItems96
19. pnlDeptItems97
20. pnlDeptItems98
21. pnlDeptItems99

Visible and Enabled are set to true for all panels on creation.

Below is the code that I use to search for the panel by name and if I find it then try to make it visible which it already is and then I try to bring it to front.  And it does absolutely nothing but keeps the 1st panel visible.

```
For Each control In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Panel)
            If control.Name = btnPanelName Then
                control.Controls.Add(oButton)
                control.Visible = True
                control.BringToFront()
                Console.WriteLine(control.Name & " " & oButton.Name)
            End If
        Next
```

CODE TO CREATE PANELS

```
  Private Sub CreateNewPanel(ByRef pnlName As String, ByRef pnltopx As Integer, ByRef pnlLefty As Integer, ByRef pnlSizex As Integer, ByRef pnlSizey As Integer)
        Dim iPanel As Panel
        iPanel = New Panel
        iPanel.Name = pnlName
        iPanel.Enabled = True
        iPanel.Visible = False
        iPanel.Top = pnltopx
        iPanel.Left = pnlLefty
        iPanel.Size = New Size(pnlSizex, pnlSizey)
        iPanel.AutoScroll = True
        Me.Controls.Add(iPanel)
        If iPanel.Name = "pnlDepartments" Or iPanel.Name = "pnlDeptItems26" Then
            iPanel.Visible = True
            iPanel.BringToFront()
        End If
    End Sub
```

I then tried doing this and this does not work either:

```
For Each control In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Panel)
            If control.Name = btnPanelName Then
                control.Controls.Add(oButton)
            End If
            If control.Name = "pnlDeptItems26" Then
                control.Visible = True

            End If
        Next
```

Code that is called to create the panels

```
CreateNewPanel("pnlDeptItems" & dataDeptId, 608, 5, 429, 479)
```

dataDeptId is pulled from a database in a loop.

Can someone explain to me why this is not working or what the work around is?  I know it has something to do with all the panels that are created being created in the exact same position.

Thanks,
Shawn Mulligan

Comment: It would be interesting to see the code creating the panels. Possibly also, all panels should be created with visible set to false, and set only the one you want as visible when you find it.

Comment: Have you actually debugged the code? I'd wager not. Set a breakpoint at the top of that `For Each` loop and actually step through it line by line. My guess would be that `control.Name` is never equal to `btnPanelName`. Either that or it's always the same `Panel` that matches. Regardless, you have a debugger in front of you so use to see what's actually happening.

Comment: By the way, you don't need a loop. Use `Dim pnl In Controls.OfType(Of Panel).First(Function(p) p.Name = btnPanelName`. If there may not be a match then use `FirstOrDefault` and check for `Nothing`.

Comment: I added more of my code.  however I can not get any of the panels to display that are in the list, with the exception of the first one called panel2.  I did have code to tell me the name of all the panels, and also all of the buttons on all of the panels after all of the creation process and it shows that they are all there, but just won't display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.  After reading my post I took notice that for some reason that my paneltopx and my panellefty were reversed and too large for some reason as well as my panelsizey and panelsizex.

I made the adjustments and made sure that all panels visibility was set to false, and now when I set visibility to true, the correct panel displays with the buttons that I created.

Thanks,
Shawn Mulligan

Comment: For future reference, it's a good idea to change the `BackColor` of `Panels` or give them a border in scenarios like this so that you can easily see what's what. That probably would have clued you in early.

Comment: I thought that you could have all the panels visible and then just bring to front the one that you need at the time that you needed it.  Yes the back color is a good suggestion.

Comment: Hi ,glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider  accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)